# Simple Drawing App In Android

Tags: java, android

As a beginner, I'm trying to create a simple drawing application in android. However, I keep running into the following issue where I am not able to press any of my buttons because a path is drawn on top of the button. How would I adjust the following code so that the ability to draw is separated from pressing buttons?

I am definitely also open to suggestions on how to decouple the drawing experience from the button clicking experience, but I am more interested in how to resolve the issue with the code I currently have as a learning experience.

To give you a better example of what I mean is :
http://imgur.com/8i1RCt7

Simplified Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    aButton = (Button) findViewById(....
        bButton = (Button) findViewById(....

    aListener = new OnClickListener(){...
    bListener = new OnClickListener(){...

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(aListener);
    clearButton.setOnClickListener(bListener);

    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    cView = new CanvasView(this);

    layout.addView(cView);

    listener = new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            float posX = event.getX();
            float posY = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                     path.moveTo(posX, posY);
                     break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                     path.lineTo(posX, posY);
                     break;
            } // ends switch statement
            cView.invalidate();
            return true;

        }

    };
    cView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Comment: This is happening because the CanvasView is taking the complete width and height as your View. What you can try is adding below the buttons in the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
cView.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW , aButton.getId());
layout.addView(cView, p);
```

Basically, this should align the canvas below the button. Currently it is overlapped.